# How do I write a batch file to feed a list of files to a format converter?

Tags: batch-file, rename

I'm using a **DBF2CSV converter** to convert a large list of dbf files. The program works in batch mode as:

```
dbf2csv.exe filename.dbf filename.csv [parameters]
```

Here's my code so far but it isn't doing anything!

```
echo off

for /r %%a in (*.dbf) do c:/dbf2csv/dbf2csv.exe %%a/*.dbf %%a/*.csv /OVERWRITE=1 /BATCH /OPEN=0  /SKIPDEL=0 /REMTRAIL=1 /HEADER=0 /QUOTES=1 /REMCRLF=1 /ASIS /YYYYMMDD /FIELDS=, /RECORDS=CRLF /ESCAPE=" >> get_files.txt
PAUSE
```

Any help with the right way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop variable `%%a` already has the .dbf filename, so your command-line should look like this:

```
for /r %%a in (*.dbf) do C:/dbf2csv/dbf2csv.exe "%%~fa" "%%~dpna.csv" ...
```